# PHP + SQL : Loop in php to get multiple WHERE conditions

Tags: php, sql

So lets say I have a list with some entries(ids) of a table. I want to get the table rows which have the exact ids as in the list. How could I formulate this in php with sql statements.

i.e

```
idList = [23,43,65,234,54];
```

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE id = 23 
AND id = 43 
AND id = 65 
AND id = 234 
AND id = 54;
```

Sorry, the AND was a mistake.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: You realize you're expecing your `id` value to be, **SIMULTANEOUSLY**, multiple different values? You're not using a quantum database.... try `... WHERE id IN (23, 43, 65, 234, 54)` as an `or` clause instead

Comment: you could also use "OR" instead of "AND", but really you should be using IN ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$list='23,43,65,234,54';
$SQL='SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE id in ('.$list.')';
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of checking each id, you can use the `IN` operator to search in a set of values:

```
SELECT * FROM kittens WHERE id IN (23,43,65,234,54)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your search is bound to return no rows as the `id` cannot have more than one value at a time.

I'm guessing you want to return rows where `id`matches either of the values in which case you can

1) Use the OR operator in place of AND

2) Or better use the IN operator